# How to store decimal value via Doctrine in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity in Symfony for an product price defined in the following way:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=12, scale=2, nullable=true)
 *
 */
private $price;
```

Now I want to store the price value **2.50**,but it rounds up to **2.00**.I have tried adding it as **(float) 2.50** or as **(string) 2.50** but it always is rounded to **2.00**.

*Looks like I'm not able to store the scale value?*

Comment: IMHO, this shouldn't be handle in the DB, it's a concern for displaying the information and as such should be handled either by the view or the controller.

Comment: But how do I then store a price value in the database? I need to know where the dot is as 250 is not the same as 2.50? Or do you store all value as integer in cents so take the price and multiply if by 100 before it goes into the database?

Comment: What I've done in the past is store the price as an integer representing pennies; $2.50 becomes 250 and $250.00 becomes 25000. Then, use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) (or the [Twig equivalent](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html)) to display the value in the view.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that is indeed the best way. Handling integer is much easier.

Answer (score 5):

## Store it as an integer

Yes, the best is to store it in cents, therefore as an integer. The trick here is to use a `DataTransformer`.

---

<kbd>Entity</kbd>

```
/**
 * Price of the option (in cents)
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $price = 0;

/**
 * @param int $price
 */
public function setPrice(?int $price): self
{
    $this->price = $price;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getPrice(): ?int
{
    return $this->price;
}
```

<kbd>Data Transformer</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class CentToDollarTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * Transforms cent to dollar amount.
     *
     * @param  int|null $priceInCent
     * @return double
     */
    public function transform($priceInCent)
    {
        if (null === $priceInCent) {
            return;
        }

        $priceInDollar = number_format(($priceInCent /100), 2, '.', ' ');

        return $priceInDollar;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms dollar to cent amount.
     *
     * @param  double|null $priceInDollar
     * @return int
     */
    public function reverseTransform($priceInDollar)
    {
        if (null === $priceInDollar) {
            return;
        }

        $priceInCent = (int)($priceInDollar * 100);

        return $priceInCent;
    }
}
```

<kbd>Form Type</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use App\Form\DataTransformer\CentToDollarTransformer;

// ...

$builder->add('price', MoneyType::class, array(
    'scale' => 2,
    'currency' => null,
    'label' => 'form.price',
    'attr' => array(
        'min' => '0.00',
        'max' => '1000.00',
        'step' => '0.01'
    )
));

$builder->get('price')
    ->addModelTransformer(new CentToDollarTransformer());
```

Comment: Or you can just use the `divisor` option https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html#divisor

Comment: Great solution! One tiny update to avoid rounding issues [link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.comparison): instead of converting float to int, I would convert float to string and then to int. `(int)((string)($priceInDollar * 100));`